# How can I make the cell colour RGB value change based on cell's value? (in Excel)

Tags: excel, colors, cell, rgb

I'm new to VBA and have tried the below which doesn't work. Could you help me fix it. I'm trying to make each cell have a different RGB colour based on it's value:

```
Sub ColorCells()

Dim rwIndex As Integer

Dim colIndex As Integer

Dim r As Integer
Dim g As Integer
Dim b As Integer


For rwIndex = 1 To 1000
        For colIndex = 1 To 1000

                r = Cells(rwIndex, colIndex).Value Mod 256
                g = Cells(rwIndex, colIndex).Value \ 256 Mod 256
                b = Cells(rwIndex, colIndex).Value \ 65536 Mod 256

                Cells(rwIndex, colIndex).Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(r, g, b)

        Next colIndex
Next rwIndex
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `ColorIndex` with `RGB`, just use `Color`

```
 Cells(rwIndex, colIndex).Interior.Color = RGB(r, g, b)
```

Assuming of course `r, g, b` are all in the `(0,255)` range